# Excel Visio Add-in: Updating excel data does not update visio org chart after editing shapes in desktop app

Tags: excel, add-in, visio, excel-addins

**Setting the stage:**

I have an excel sheet with my employee data that is connected to the visio add-in. Once I completed the data needed for the add-in, the add-in created the org chart. All good, except, the org chart is very wide/horizontal. So I open the org chart in the desktop app so I can edit the hierarchy of the shapes (not changing any hierarchies, just moving the shapes around so it becomes more vertical instead of horizontal).

**PROBLEM:**

Once I finished editing the org chart in visio desktop app, I need to add in another employee, so I added that data into the excel sheet, then go to refresh the visio add-in, but the refreshed org chart does not pick up my newly added data. It just shows the exact org chart that I edited in the desktop app. I need the visio add-in to be able to pick up the updated data, whether it is employees added in, or deleted, or other data slightly changed, but it is not picking up this information.

The only thing I've been able to do is to remove the add-in and re-add it again, but then I have to go back into the desktop app and move around the shapes to my liking, and that becomes very cumbersome and something I'm trying to omit. I can't do that every time data is updated.

What can I do???? Please help.

Microsoft Visio LTSC Professional 2021
Version 2308